# APL - Why does this produce a multiplication table?

Tags: apl

I (accidentally) wrote the following function in APL:

```
{⍳⍵ ⍵}
```

I was surprised that when I call this function [(verify it)](https://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%u2373%u2375%20%u2375%7D%203&run), it produces a valid multiplication table:

```
      {⍳⍵ ⍵} 3
┌───┬───┬───┐
│1 1│1 2│1 3│
├───┼───┼───┤
│2 1│2 2│2 3│
├───┼───┼───┤
│3 1│3 2│3 3│
└───┴───┴───┘
```

Using my current knowledge in APL, I can't understand exactly how this produces a valid multiplication table, since I didn't properly write an inner product over here.

Answer (score 2):

Monadic `⍳` is the [Index Generator](http://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/Primitive%20Functions/Index%20Generator.htm). which takes the shape of an array `s` as its sole argument. It generates an array of shape `s` where every element is the index to that element:

```
      ⍳5  ⍝ vector
1 2 3 4 5
      ⍳2 3  ⍝ matrix
┌───┬───┬───┐
│1 1│1 2│1 3│
├───┼───┼───┤
│2 1│2 2│2 3│
└───┴───┴───┘
      ⍳2 3 4  ⍝ block of 2 layers, each with 3 rows and 4 columns
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│1 1 1│1 1 2│1 1 3│1 1 4│
├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│1 2 1│1 2 2│1 2 3│1 2 4│
├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│1 3 1│1 3 2│1 3 3│1 3 4│
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│2 1 1│2 1 2│2 1 3│2 1 4│
├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│2 2 1│2 2 2│2 2 3│2 2 4│
├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│2 3 1│2 3 2│2 3 3│2 3 4│
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

While you call the result a multiplication table, there's no multiplication going on, only juxtaposition of the indices along each axis. However, you're right that this resembles *outer* (not *inner*) product with the concatenation function (`∘.,`):

```
      (⍳2)∘.,(⍳3)
┌───┬───┬───┐
│1 1│1 2│1 3│
├───┼───┼───┤
│2 1│2 2│2 3│
└───┴───┴───┘
```

Comment: I never used `⍳` with two or more right arguments... Now I found it in the reference.

Comment: @a'_' Technically speaking, it is only one right argument, though one with multiple elements.